# Reflection shifts when trying to make a normal map stronger (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normal-map, reflection

How to avoid it? I cant apply the normal map correctly

[image: Strenght = 3]
[image: Strength = 0]

[[image: Strenght = 1][2]]

Comment: what is the rest of your node organisation? how does your normal image looks like? why are you not happy with the result? maybe pack the images and share just the ground so that we can test?

Comment: Is your Normal Map texture set to non-color space (it should be)?

Comment: yep, its set to non-color data @ChristopherBennett

Comment: @moonboots typical nodes. image texture + normal map + principled bsdf, textures from poliigon

Comment: it's what happening if you push it too strong, and you can't push the contrasts like with a height map, maybe the normal map is too subtle, you could recreate one from your wood texture with a software like Crazybump and make contrasted enough? Or create a height map instead?